# Including dotfiles in grunt-zip

Tags: gruntjs

As part of my Gruntfile.js I have the following:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  zip: {
    app: {
      files: [
        {
          src: [ '**/*', "!./app/cache/**", '!./app/logs/**' ],
          dest: 'archive.zip',
          dot: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-zip');
```

However when I run `grunt zip:app` no dotfiles get included in the resulting zip file.  For example `.travis.yml` is present in the source tree, but not in the zip.

I'm knew to Grunt so it's not obvious what I've done wrong; but I do want those dotfiles in the zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the module; see https://github.com/twolfson/grunt-zip/issues/10